# Kernel crashes when writing to VESA framebuffer after loading IDT

Tags: c++, assembly, kernel, interrupt, osdev

I am writing to the framebuffer provided by the grub multiboot, everything is fine until i initialize the interrupt descriptor table, after that when trying to write again to the framebuffer the kernel crashes. (the interrupts works fine, like the keyboard or mouse)

Here is my loader:

Loader.asm

```s
.set MAGIC, 0x1BADB002
.set FLAGS, 0b00000111
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section .multiboot
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM

.long 0
.long 0
.long 0
.long 0
.long 0

.long 0
.long 1024
.long 768
.long 24

.section .text
.extern KernelMain
.extern ConstructorsCall
.global loader

loader:
    cli
    cld

    mov $kernelStack, %esp
    call ConstructorsCall

    push %eax
    push %ebx
    call KernelMain

.section .bss
.space 2 * 1024 * 1024
kernelStack:
```

Here is my main function for initializing the kernel:

Kernel.cpp

```cpp
#include <HardwareCommunication/InterruptManager.h>

#include <Drivers/Keyboard.h>
#include <Drivers/Driver.h>
#include <Drivers/Mouse.h>

#include <Common/Console.h>
#include <Common/Types.h>

#include <GlobalDescriptorTable.h>
#include <Miscellaneous.h>

extern "C" constructor_t constructorsStart, constructorsEnd;

extern "C" void ConstructorsCall()
{
    for (constructor_t *i = &constructorsStart; i != &constructorsEnd; i++)
    {
        (*i)();
    }
}

static unsigned char g_8x8_font[] = {}; // too large to include this here

int strlen(const char *string)
{
    int length = 0;
    while (string[length++] != 0)
        ;
    return length - 1;
}

unsigned int *framebuffer;

void printf(const char *string, int x, int y)
{
    x *= 8;
    y *= 8;

    int pos = 1024 * y + x;

    for (int s = 0; s < strlen(string); s++, pos += 8)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++)
            {
                if ((g_8x8_font[string[s] * 8 + j] >> l) & 1)
                {
                    framebuffer[pos + 1024 * j + 8 - l] = 0xFFFFFF;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extern "C" void KernelMain(uint32_t *multiBootHeader)
{
    framebuffer = (unsigned int *)multiBootHeader[22];

    GlobalDescriptorTable globalDescriptorTable;
    InterruptManager interruptManager(globalDescriptorTable);

    printf("Initializing Hardware...", 0, 0);
    KeyboardDriver keyboardDriver(interruptManager);
    MouseDriver mouseDriver(interruptManager);

    printf("Activating Hardware...", 0, 2);
    DriverManager driverManager;
    driverManager.Add(&keyboardDriver);
    driverManager.Add(&mouseDriver);
    driverManager.ActivateAll();

    interruptManager.Activate();

    SystemDateTime sdt = Miscellaneous::ReadRTCAndConvert();
    // printf("Flexible@OS ~ $ ", 0, 8); //----------------------------------------- Here It Crashes. :(

    Miscellaneous::SoundBeep();

    while (true)
    {
    }
}
```

InterruptManager.cpp

```cpp
#include <HardwareCommunication/InterruptManager.h>

InterruptManager::gateDescriptor_s InterruptManager::s_interruptDescriptorTable[256];
InterruptManager *InterruptManager::s_activeInterruptManager = nullptr;

InterruptManager::InterruptManager(const InterruptManager &interruptManager)
{
    Memory::Copy(this, &interruptManager, sizeof(interruptManager));
}

void InterruptManager::Activate()
{
    if (s_activeInterruptManager != nullptr)
    {
        s_activeInterruptManager->Deactivate();
    }

    s_activeInterruptManager = this;

    asm("sti");
}

void InterruptManager::Deactivate()
{
    if (s_activeInterruptManager == this)
    {
        s_activeInterruptManager = nullptr;

        asm("cli");
    }
}

InterruptManager::InterruptManager(GlobalDescriptorTable &globalDescriptorTable)
    : picMasterCommand(0x20),
      picMasterData(0x21),
      picSlaveCommand(0xA0),
      picSlaveData(0xA1)
{
    uint16_t codeSegment = globalDescriptorTable.GetCodeSegmentSelector();
    const uint8_t IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE = 0xE;

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        interruptHandlers[i] = nullptr;
        SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(i, codeSegment, &InterruptIgnore, 0, IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE);
    }

    SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(0x20, codeSegment, &HandleInterruptRequest0x00, 0, IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE);
    SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(0x21, codeSegment, &HandleInterruptRequest0x01, 0, IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE);
    SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(0x2C, codeSegment, &HandleInterruptRequest0x0C, 0, IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE);

    picMasterCommand.Write(0x11);
    picSlaveCommand.Write(0x11);

    picMasterData.Write(0x20);
    picSlaveData.Write(0x28);

    picMasterData.Write(0x04);
    picSlaveData.Write(0x02);

    picMasterData.Write(0x01);
    picSlaveData.Write(0x01);

    picMasterData.Write(0x00);
    picSlaveData.Write(0x00);

    interruptDescriptorTable_s interruptDescriptorTable;
    interruptDescriptorTable.m_size = 256 * sizeof(gateDescriptor_s) - 1;
    interruptDescriptorTable.m_base = (uint32_t)s_interruptDescriptorTable;

    asm volatile("lidt %0"
                 :
                 : "m"(interruptDescriptorTable));
}

void InterruptManager::SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(uint8_t interruptNumber, uint16_t codeSegmentSelectorOffset, void (*handler)(), uint8_t descriptorPrivilegeLevel, uint8_t descriptorType)
{
    const uint8_t IDT_DESC_PRESENT = 0x80;

    s_interruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].m_handlerAddressLowBits = ((uint32_t)handler) & 0xFFFF;
    s_interruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].m_handlerAddressHighBits = (((uint32_t)handler) >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
    s_interruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].m_gdtCodeSegmentSelector = codeSegmentSelectorOffset;
    s_interruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].m_access = IDT_DESC_PRESENT | descriptorType | ((descriptorPrivilegeLevel & 3) << 5);
    s_interruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].m_reserved = 0;
}

uint32_t InterruptManager::HandleInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNumber, uint32_t esp)
{
    if (s_activeInterruptManager != nullptr)
    {
        return s_activeInterruptManager->DoHandleInterrupt(interruptNumber, esp);
    }

    return esp;
}

uint32_t InterruptManager::DoHandleInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNumber, uint32_t esp)
{
    if (interruptHandlers[interruptNumber] != 0)
    {
        esp = interruptHandlers[interruptNumber]->HandleInterrupt(esp);
    }
    else if (interruptNumber != 0x20)
    {
        char message[] = "UNHANDLED INTERRUPT 0x00";
        const char *hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        message[22] = hex[(interruptNumber >> 4) & 0x0F];
        message[23] = hex[interruptNumber & 0x0F];

        // Console::Write(message);
    }

    if (0x20 <= interruptNumber && interruptNumber < 0x30)
    {
        picMasterCommand.Write(0x20);

        if (0x28 <= interruptNumber)
        {
            picSlaveCommand.Write(0x20);
        }
    }

    return esp;
}

InterruptHandler::InterruptHandler(uint8_t interruptNumber, InterruptManager &interruptManager)
{
    this->interruptNumber = interruptNumber;
    this->interruptManager = &interruptManager;

    interruptManager.interruptHandlers[interruptNumber] = this;
}

uint32_t InterruptHandler::HandleInterrupt(uint32_t esp)
{
    return esp;
}

InterruptHandler::~InterruptHandler()
{
    if (interruptManager->interruptHandlers[interruptNumber] == this)
    {
        interruptManager->interruptHandlers[interruptNumber] = nullptr;
    }
}

InterruptHandler::InterruptHandler(const InterruptHandler &interruptHandler)
{
    Memory::Copy(this, &interruptHandler, sizeof(interruptHandler));
}
```

I don't want to spam with code so i will link the project so you can see the garbage https://github.com/ClaudiuHBann/FlexibleOS

Edit: I added the InterruptManager.cpp

Comment: I added 'osdev' tag and removed 'crash' to make it fit

Comment: If you comment out `interruptManager.Activate();` (which presumably sets the IDT pointer) then it works fine? How do you know the problem is because of `printf` and not because of `ReadRTCAndConvert`? Are you testing in an emulator? If so, the emulator may be able to tell you what is happening. Why is the relevant code for InterruptManager missing?

Comment: if i comment interruptManager.Activate(); it works fine (it's drawing on screen, but of course the drivers stop working)
ReadRTCAndConvert just takes the data from CMOS, doesn't affect anything i can comment it
I am testing in vmware, i dont know how to open a background console for vmware to give me info about the vm, if that is possible
the code for the interruptmanager was in the link i provided, i dint wanted to post hundreds of lines, but i will add that too

Comment: VMware probably won't give you detailed info - I was thinking qemu or bochs

Comment: You shouldn't post hundreds of lines. You should post the smallest amount of code that still makes the problem happen. Make a copy of your project. Delete everything irrelevant until the problem goes away, then put back the last part you deleted. Then keep deleting as much as you can.

Comment: Why would you want `InterruptManager::Activate()` to call `Deactivate()` to run a `cli` right before running an `sti`?  Also, crashes where?  Use a debugger (like the one built-in to Bochs) to see what fault is happening where.  Alternatives are GDB attaching to QEMU, which would let you do source-level debugging.

Comment: i tried using qemu console but no errors pop up

Comment: Run QEMU with the `-d int -no-reboot -no-shutdown` options. It should print all the exceptions raised and all pertinent information regarding them. This info will include external interrupts and faults.

Comment: I did that already: "qemu-system-i386 "iso file path" -d int -no-reboot -no-shutdown" but no errors show up, the kernel runs but not correctly (draws wrong on screen)

Comment: vmware says that it is a fault but the logs dont contain anything about it or i dont know wehere to look and the qemu dont print in the console the fault, it just works....

Comment: in QEMU it prints stuff on the screen but wrong, the keyboard doesnt work (interrupts in general) and the console from QEMU doesnt print any errors like triple fault

Comment: "You shouldn't post hundreds of lines. You should post the smallest amount of code that still makes the problem happen"

Comment: @ClaudiuHBann can you post the full code that causes issues on some branch on your github? With all the info that's not included in the post (like `// too large to include this here`)

Comment: i did include the project from github it's at the bottom or [link](https://github.com/ClaudiuHBann/FlexibleOS)

Comment: @ClaudiuHBann yes, you did include it but the version on Github is different than in this post. At least the kernel.cpp